# delete data Array from node js mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have this code that allows me to delete data from mongoDB using node js but what I'm looking for is to delete the entire array `eventsFollowing`and I could figure out how to do it .

The array that I want to delete  is below

[image]

the code that I'm using now is below :

```
exports.deletfollow = async (req, res, next) => {
  Author = req.body.userId;
  console.log(Author);
  eventFollowingId = req.body.followingId;
  User.update({ _id: Author }, { $unset: { eventsFollowing: "" } });
};
```

Any suggestions ?

Best Regards

Comment: put `await` before update query, `await User.update(`